# Cannot create a trigger from the migration

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, triggers, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and a SQL Server database. I'm trying to create a trigger that fires when inserting data into a specific table.

I have created this trigger in SQL Server and it's firing correctly, now I wanted to include the trigger in the migration so that the trigger works on the newly seeded data as well (since the migration drops and rebuilds the database).

Here's my trigger in SQL Server:

```
USE [XDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[X] 
ON [dbo].[XX] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id int;
    DECLARE @typeId int;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @id = id FROM inserted;
    SELECT @typeId = TYPE_ID FROM inserted;
    
    IF (@typeId = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO XXX 
        VALUES (@id, 7)
    END
END
```

and it was working just fine.

And here is how I included it in the migration :

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(
                + "CREATE TRIGGER X"
                + "ON XX"
                + "AFTER INSERT"
                + "AS"
                + "BEGIN"
                + "declare @Id int;"
                + "declare @typeId int;"
                + "SET NOCOUNT ON;"
                + "select @id = id from inserted;"
                + "select @typeId = TYPE_ID from inserted;"
                + "if (@typeId = 1)"
                + "begin"
                + "insert into XXX"
                + "values(@id, 7)"
                + "end"
                + "END"
                + "ALTER TABLE users ENABLE TRIGGER[X]");
```

**What I expect**

When updating the database and the migration is applied, the trigger should be present under its table and the new seeded data will change according to the trigger.

**What's actually happening**

The trigger is not even created. the rest of the migration is working perfectly, the database and tables are created and the data is seeded.

**What I tried**

First the trigger was at the bottom of the migration , after the data insertion commands, so I moved it to the top. but that did not work.

Then I removed the "[dbo].[XNAMe]" from the trigger, thinking that maybe this was SQL Server specific naming, but that also did not work.

Comment: The trigger is flawed; it ***assumes*** that a `INSERT` only ever contains 1 row. This is simply not true.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: Your trigger is *not* working on a `set`. Tables are `sets`

Comment: @Larnu yeah that makes sense. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Read the article I linked, @AtaaAub .

Comment: wow okay I really didn't know about any of this. thanks a lot for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger simply needs to be along the lines of (I assume it's a cut-down example)

```
create trigger [dbo].[X] 
on  [dbo].[XX] 
after insert
as 
set nocount on
if @@RowCount=0 return

insert into XXX
select id,7
from inserted
where type_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

so as @larnu and @stu pointed out, my trigger was flawed and I was not preparing it for multirow insert.
but that observation still left out why the trigger wasn't even created in the first place.
(the migration executed without errors).

and after a lot of research and trial and error, I solved it, and I'm laying it here in case someone faces the same issue.

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(
               "CREATE TRIGGER[dbo].[X]"
                + " ON[dbo].[XX]"
                + " AFTER INSERT"
                + " AS"
                + " BEGIN"
                + " declare @x_id int ;"
                + " declare @count int;"
                + " SET NOCOUNT ON;"
                + " select @count = count(*) from INSERTED"
                + " if (@count = 0) return"
                + " DECLARE inserted_cursor CURSOR"
                + " FOR select x_id from inserted"
                + " open inserted_cursor"
                + " FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor into @x_id;"
                + " WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0"
                + " BEGIN"
                + " insert into xxx"
                + " values(@x_id, 8)"
                + " FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor into @x_id;"
                + " END;"
                + " CLOSE inserted_cursor;"
                + " DEALLOCATE inserted_cursor;"
                + " END");
```

what the trigger does :

- fires after inserting a row in table 'XX' (alias)
- makes sure that at least one row was inserted.
- declares a cursor that should loop through the inserted row(s) and
  opens it.
- fetches the next inserted row.
- here the loop begins:

  1. make sure that the fetch was executed without errors
  2. insert the desired data (what the trigger is made for)
  3. fetch the next row
- then back to the beginning of the loop
- and lastly it closes the cursor and releases it.

The result is the migration successfully created the trigger, and the newly inserted data were affected by it (as intended.)

resources : [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fetch-status-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) , [this](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/#:%7E:text=To%20declare%20a%20cursor%2C%20you,result%20set%20for%20the%20cursor.) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/cursor-in-sql-server/)

Comment: But that still doesn't clarify why the original code didn't run. I think it's because the leading spaces were missing (yielding `CREATE TRIGGER XON XXAFTER INSERT...`), but then the migration should have thrown an exception. And yet again, about the trigger: it can be a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM INSERTED`. Cursors can often be replaced by more optimal set-based code. Also, a non-local cursor there is a potential source of exceptions.